# APIs integrations without asking for secrets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, integration

I need to build APIs integrations to connect my Rails 6 B2B app to any other service such as Google Drive, Microsoft Excel, Zapier.

What I've done so far is to ask clients for their `client_id` and `client_secret` (or `api_key`), store them and then use them to authenticate to the API with OAuth2.

Storing clients' secrets is not the ideal solution. I would like to do the same thing but without asking for secrets.

Just like Trello or TypeForm are doing it.

I have no clue on how to authorize my app to read/write data of an other service without authorizing through an URL with the secrets.

Here is an example of TypeForm connecting to GoogleSheet API :

- Connects to the Google account
- Asks for permissions
- Asks for the spreadsheet link
- Writes data in the spreadsheet (form responses)

https://www.typeform.com/connect/google-sheets/send-responses-to-google-sheets/

Comment: Which authentication you are using, you have to use `omniauth` in which you will allow other authentication methods like Goodl, and add button for user to login, when they will click, it will take permission and send token to call back url

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is that you register your own "app" in the console for those API providers, and then you use your own client id/secret pair to request access to the end user's data. That's what usually brings up those authorization screens like: "jdps app1 would like to access your google account".

More information for Google APIs specifically: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2